# image file not correct when upload into AWS S3 using axios

Tags: php, laravel, axios

Im new for using AXIOS. Currently, i'm developing laravel framework combine with AXIOS code.

I use axios code for getting image URL and store it into AWS S3. i can able to store the image into S3, but the image file is not correct. the image file just a icon image. not the image from the image URL.

here is the code

```
axios.get('https://www.instagram.com/p/B_zZCRpB895/media/?size=t', { responseType: "blob" })
      .then(function (response) { 
        var reader = new window.FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(response.data);
        reader.onload = function () {  
          var imageDataUrl = reader.result; 
 
          var params = { 
                    Bucket: 'thumbnail', 
                    Key: 'shortlist/image.jpg', 
                    Body: imageDataUrl
          };
          s3.upload(params, function (err, data) { 
              console.log('result:');
              console.log(err, data);
              console.log('\n');
              var s3url = data.Location;

              console.log('s3 url: ' + s3url); 
          });

        }

      });
```

code  `var imageDataUrl = reader.result;`  return this result

```
image/jpeg;base64,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..........
```

how do i able to upload that result image into S3 with correct image file?

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your base64 image to blob, then use the stream to upload to S3:

```
      ...
 
      var imageDataUrl = reader.result; 

      fetch(imageDataUrl)
         .then(res => res.blob())
            .then(blob => {

               //blob is your binary file
               var params = { 
                    Bucket: 'thumbnail', 
                    Key: 'shortlist/image.jpg', 
                    Body: blob
               };

              s3.upload(params, function (err, data) { 
              console.log('result:');
              console.log(err, data);
              console.log('\n');
              var s3url = data.Location;
              console.log('s3 url: ' + s3url); 
      });
              })
```